# Getting a error while using npm

Tags: node.js

I am getting this error while using npm.

'CALL "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules
\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" prefix -g' is not recognized as an internal or external com
mand,
operable program or batch file.
5.6.0

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add in post what command you trying and  error log

Comment: that comes every time i use npm, anyways i got above error while checking npm version npm -v

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed Node.js and still can't use it through command line then you should set the environment variable for Node.js

You can use this link as well for a reference: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hiVKXJ2hAdo